Mock test HTTP Calls form a Real Server
I have been looking for an application that could proxy, record and replay requests from a Server, That could be used for tests.
Essentially for scenarios where we would like to initially capture the response from a server from the client for the first time and thereafter anytime we'd like to to tests on the client, we can rely on the recordings rather than hit the actual server everytime.
Essentially a solution like vcr or go-vcr but as an externally proxy or process rather than something embedded to test cases. Mainly in these scenarios we have to source code for the client and we can inject a modified HTTP client of sorts.
The use case I'm looking for we don't have a way to inject any modification to the client code, the client code hits the External Proxy process that can replay requests for the original server after a recording just like vcr, but as a separate process.

The proxy is a separate external process.
For Eg, Id like to capture the request between a client like Curl and the server.
And after recording is when, when curl hits the request through the proxy, the proxy replays the request.
Is there such a utility? Help and suggestions are much appreciated.
